# Where can I find my "PROJECT_SENDER_ID" (or project number) in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Some years ago it was at the Dashboard screen, but now I don't find it.
Does it became hidden because the new FCM?

Answer (score 1):

The Sender ID needed from GCM/FCM is the same as the Project ID.

If you're accessing it from the [Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com), just go to:

1. The more options (kebab) button on the top right corner.
2. Project Settings.
3. See *Project Number*